# Redirecting domains to local addresses

Tags: networking, dns, routes, openvpn

Clients are connecting to private servers using OpenVPN, currently using raw IPs (`172.X.X.X`) but I would like to point more user-friendly subdomains (`something.ourdomain.com`) to those private IPs

Key is to

- **Not make our private topology public**, so binding subdomains to a public DNS is not an option
- **Be able to push new settings to all clients efficiently**, so modifying local hosts-files whenever a private IP updates could potentially be cumbersome
- **Not tie the routing to a specific local hardware**, so doing the routing on say e.g. our office router is not really an option

Any suggestions how to achieve this considering the above points? Set-up a private DNS? Do the routing in OpenVPN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Set-up private DNS server(s)

2) Push DNS server to your OpenVPN clients by addding

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.X.X.X"
```

to your OpenVPN server configuration (where `172.X.X.X` is private IP address of your DNS server)